# Why does wordexp fail with WRDE_SYNTAX on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line

I'm using [wordexp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp) for command-line parsing in an OS X program, and no matter what I pass in for the input string, it always returns `WRDE_SYNTAX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wordexp` will always fail with `WRDE_SYNTAX` if you have set the SIGCHLD signal to be ignored like so: `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)`. A library may be doing this without your knowledge. Presumably the implementation of `wordexp` on OS X actually spawns a shell as a child process to do the parsing.

The solution is to call `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL)` before `wordexp`. You can restore `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)` afterward.